# ASP.NET Core MVC not showing dynamic image

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to make a blog in ASP.NET Core.

So, in the post's model it saves the name of the image, the it's in the `wwwroot/content/blog`.

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0036)https://localhost:44318/Home/Post/10 -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale-1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="https://localhost:44318/">Home</a>
        <a href="https://localhost:44318/Panel/Edit">Create Post</a>
        <a href="https://localhost:44318/Panel">Admin Panel</a>
            <a href="https://localhost:44318/Auth/Logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>titulo</h2>


    <img scr="/Image/img_17-02-2021-19-17-21.PNG">

<p>teste tstet etste teste teste teste tetse testte </p>
    </div>

</body></html>
```

The HomeController:

```
using blog.Data;
using blog.Data.FileManager;
using blog.Data.Repository;
using blog.Models;
using blog.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace blog.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository _repo;
        private IFileManager _fileManager;

        public HomeController(IRepository repo, IFileManager fileManager)
        {
            _repo = repo;
            _fileManager = fileManager;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var posts = _repo.GetAllPosts();
            return View(posts);
        }
        public IActionResult Post(int id)
        {
            var post = _repo.GetPost(id);
            return View(post);
        }
        [HttpGet("/Image/{image}")]
        public IActionResult Image(string image)
        {
            var mime = image.Substring(image.LastIndexOf('.')+1);
            return new FileStreamResult(_fileManager.ImageStream(image), $"Image/{mime}");
        }
    }
}
```

And the FileManager:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace blog.Data.FileManager
{
    public class FileManager : IFileManager
    {
        private string _imagePath;

        public FileManager(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _imagePath = config["Path:Images"];
        }

        public FileStream ImageStream(string image)
        {
            return new FileStream(Path.Combine(_imagePath, image), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        }

        public async Task<string> SaveImage(IFormFile image)
        {
            try
            {
                var save_path = Path.Combine(_imagePath);
                if (!Directory.Exists(_imagePath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(save_path);
                }

                var mime = image.FileName.Substring(image.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                var fileName = $"img_{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss}{mime}";

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(save_path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
                return fileName;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return "Error";
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently, it saves the image without problems, you can access it in the url `https://localhost:44318/Image/image_name` and in the file explorer. But, in the HTML file, it does not show nothing. It doesn't have an error in the nav console or anything and it seems like it's not hitting the `Image` method in `HomeController`.

You also can put the image :

```
<img src="~/content/blog/img_16-02-2021-18-16-58.png" />
```

and it will work.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Please `View Source` in the browser and show us the actual HTML.

Comment: I changed! Sorry, first time posting

Comment: `scr` and `src` aren't the same thing.

Comment: Yes, the file manager suposed to deal with that. But even when they are the same. I'm gonna update the post for you see

Comment: I mean you **literally misspellt `src`**.

Comment: OH SHIT, it worked now. I'M SO SORRY and thank you very much